# Silverlight Without XAML - Images Will Not Render

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I have a Silverlight application in which I'm not using XAML.  I have a basic application with the following code in Application_Startup:

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
     Grid g = new Grid();
     g.Children.Add(new Image { Source = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri("http://sstatic.net/so/img/sprites.png", UriKind.Absolute)) });
     this.RootVisual = g;
}
```

This code will not render the specified image.  If however, the App.Xaml file is modified to define the RootVisual in the Xaml the following works:

xaml:

```
<Application.RootVisual>
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</Application.RootVisual>
```

code:

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
     ((Grid)this.RootVisual).Children.Add(new Image { Source = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri("http://sstatic.net/so/img/sprites.png", UriKind.Absolute)) });
}
```

I don't see why one would work and the other not.  I have the same behavior using a UserControl as well (using Content instead of Childern of course).

From what I understand, there should be not XAML requirement.  Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

The difference is in the first case you are setting the `RootVisual` to be a `Grid`, but in the second your grid is a child element.

On the MSDN page for the [RootVisual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190010%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) property it shows the following example:

```
this.RootVisual = new Page();
```

so if you create a `Page` and then add your `Grid` to that page it should work.

```
Page page = new Page();
page.Content = g;
this.RootVisual = page;
```