# Silverlight without XAML makes source URIs fail?

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I'm in the process of removing the XAML from my Silverlight project and making it use only code (as per [this article](http://www.michaelsnow.com/2010/06/01/silverlight-tip-of-the-day-26-changing-the-startup-class/)).

Here is my very simple startup event for a Silverlight application (with the standard App.xaml from the template project):

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    Grid grid = new MainPage();
    this.RootVisual = grid;

    var mediaElement = new MediaElement();
    mediaElement.MediaFailed += (s, ea) => { mediaFailed = true; };
    mediaElement.Source = new Uri(@"/Content/Some Music.mp3", UriKind.Relative);
    grid.Children.Add(mediaElement);
}
```

Where the MP3 file is set to "Build Action: None, Copy if newer" (ie: it's beside the XAP). Here's the XAML for MainPage:

```
<Grid x:Class="TestGame.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
</Grid>
```

And the C# - nothing unusual here at all.

```
public partial class MainPage : Grid
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**That all works so far. So my question is this:** why is it that when I change

```
Grid grid = new MainPage();
```

to

```
Grid grid = new Grid();
```

the `mediaElement.MediaFailed` event gets called (with a AG_E_NETWORK_ERROR)?

The only interesting thing that `InitializeComponent` is doing is calling `Application.LoadComponent` (it's the default generated code). So what might that function be doing that allows source URIs to work?

It seems that `Application.GetResourceStream` still works just fine. But I need to be able to get a few resources external to the XAP.

(Note: it seems [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146409/silverlight-without-xaml-images-will-not-render) is having the same problem - but no one answered his question.)

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this problem, where is the "Content" folder relative to the "ClientBin" folder containing the Xap?  Is is child or a sibling?

Comment: @Anthony: I have no ClientBin folder - it's a standalone project running from the file system. The Content folder is a sibling of the XAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key factor is **UriKind.Relative**.  The question is to what is it relative?

One of the effects of `LoadComponent` is that it shifts the location of "/".  Before `LoadComponent` executes the path "/" refers to the same location as it would do in the host browser.  After `LoadComponent` "/" refers to a hybrid of the root contents of the Xap and the folder that contains the Xap.

Since you are running this via a standalone test html page "/" in your second example refers to the root of the physical drive, e.g. "c:\".

If you change the Url to "Content/Some Music.mp3" (that is remove the "/" prefix) and assuming your test html page is the same folder as the Xap it should work as expected.

Note you can't escape the hybrid path with the parent path "..", Silverlight doesn't let you do that.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. For everyone's reference, here's the http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc296240(VS.95).aspx documentation your answer lead me too (I'll have to re-read it myself later, it's pretty obtuse and I don't fully understand it yet). I think in my case I will just have to have some XAML - because my deployed XAP (and associated content) will be referenced from HTML at an unspecified URL.